# How to avoid slow collapse when using bootstrap collapse and div in a table

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

I use bootstrap and jquery to build collapsible elements. When using them outside a HTML table, it works fine, however when I use it inside a table, there is a noticable short time until the item collapses, expanding is fine as well.

See this [JSFiddle Snippet](https://jsfiddle.net/centic/k2od0ntj/)

Any clue? The full HTML code of a sample page is as follows

```
<html>
  <head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.4/css/bootstrap.min.css">
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.2.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.4/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div class="container">
        <a href="#" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#querybox">normal collapse</a>
        <div id="querybox" class="collapse">
            some long text<br/>
            some long text<br/>
            some long text<br/>
            some long text<br/>
            some long text<br/>
            some long text<br/>
            some long text<br/>
            some long text<br/>
            some long text<br/>
            some long text<br/>
            some long text<br/>
            some long text<br/>
        </div>
        <table>
        <tr>
            <td>
                <a href="#" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#contentholder1">slow collapse</a>
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr id="contentholder1" class="collapse">
            <td>234</td>
            <td>
                <div>
                    sometext<br/>
                    sometext<br/>
                    sometext<br/>
                    sometext<br/>
                    sometext<br/>
                    sometext<br/>
                    sometext<br/>
                    sometext<br/>
                    sometext<br/>
                    sometext<br/>
                    sometext<br/>
                    sometext<br/>
                    sometext<br/>
                </div>
            </td>
        </tr>                                                                           
        </table>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: There a lot of issues regarding the animation of `table` and related elements such as `tr`, `td` and `th`. The short answer here is *don't* animate them - it's not very cross-browser consistent. If you can, use other elements for all animations.

Comment: It cannot as `tbody` doesn't accept height, and that's how we animate the collapse as display is not animatable.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Try performing the collapse on the `DIV` inside your `TR`. Table elements have a different `display` style and I think this is what is causing the difference in effect.

Example using `table` https://jsfiddle.net/k2od0ntj/1/

Alternatively, do you really need a table to represent your data? You could use `div`s, along with the `display` options used by the table elements to create the same effect and change the `display` style on `.collapsing` which is applied [during transition](http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#collapse-example).

```
<div class="div-table">       <!-- <table> -->
    <div class="div-tr">      <!--   <tr> -->
        <div class="div-td">  <!--    <td> -->
            <a data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#contentholder1">slow collapse</a>
        </div>
     </div>
     <div id="contentholder1" class="div-tr collapse">
         <div class="div-tr">
```

Example without `table`: https://jsfiddle.net/k2od0ntj/3/

Comment: That basically works, but I have actually multiple td-elements and with a div i can only collapse one of them, not multiple in one go, I have updated the question and the jsfiddle accordingly, but according to comments above it may not be possible to do this :(

Comment: Interesting.. well, I have added an alternative approach to my answer. It seems to do the trick in the jsfiddle, and doesn't include the tables any longer - maybe give that a try?

Comment: Yeah, I should probably switch to div anyway, but unfortunately that is quite a bit more work in the actual application. Anyway, thanks for the suggestions.